# What are these fruits / berries from the Rocky Mountain National Park?

Tags: identification, fruit-trees, fruits, wildlife, berries

While hiking in the Rocky Mountain National Park near Estes Park, we came across the following berries / fruits. What are they?

Some info: The berries/fruits were relatively squishy. The inside contained a row of seeds similar to that of a pepper. However, the inside was filled with a clear, syrupy jelly.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of research, I determined that the plant was a [streptopus amplexifolius (aka clasping twistedstalk)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streptopus_amplexifolius)

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. It's always good when something is properly identified. We appreciate you letting us know so people who come by in the future won't have to guess!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like watermelon berry.  And yes, it tastes like watermelon.

Comment: Thanks for answering but we are looking for a more complete answer.  What species, where does it grow?

Comment: I had to do a little Googling to find more details, but it looks like you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks a lot like a solomon's seal (Polygonatum biflorum) to me!  The problem is that most true solomons seal I know of have dark blue/purplish  berries.  This could be a different variety/close relative.